# she loves her dog more than her husband

Tags: ambiguity

I have come across the following sentences in a study material supplied by The English and foreign languages University:

> 1. She loves her dog more than her husband.
> 2. They are flying saucers
> 3. They are entertaining girls

I have some questions regarding these sentences. We can analyse the sentences and explain the ambiguity.

But can people interpret these sentences in two different ways?

Do native speakers and non-native speakers of English understand these sentences in the same way?

Comment: That doggerel actually is a hair ambiguous.  The other two not so, absent context that clues a different interpretation.

Comment: @HotLicks.The other two sentences are also ambiguous

Comment: Those examples may be technically ambiguous from a sentence structure analysis perspective, but in actual use I as a native English speaker don't find any of them at all ambiguous. For the third one I would need context to be sure of the right interpretation, but even that one would be unambiguous in context.

Comment: @GEdgar - This *is* english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: “She loves her dog more than her husband does” is the way to express the second meaning. A writer who wants to be understood should find a way to be unambiguous, if a sentence is likely to cause confusion in context.

Comment: 'Flying saucers' is such an established expression that a native speaker would be unlikely to understand (2) in another way. In spoken language, the meaning intended by (3) would be obvious from the intonation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three sentences, as they stand, are ambiguous.

> 1. She loves her dog more than her husband.

- She loves her dog more than she loves her husband.
- She loves her dog more than her husband loves her dog.

> 2. They are flying saucers.

- The people are engaged in the activity of making saucers fly.
- The objects in the sky are UFOs.

> 3. They are entertaining girls.

- They are doing things so that girls have a good time.
- The girls are employed in the entertainment business.
- The girls are fun to be around.

---

The only way to tell for certain which meaning is actually meant is either through more explicit phrasing or through context that makes it obvious.

In reality, however, most people would assume the second sentence to have the second meanings—simply because that's the meaning most commonly conveyed. The third sentence is less obvious, as each meaning is used on occasion. And the first depends on how cynical you might be—although some people might think that the first meaning is quite possible.

In almost any actual conversation, or any descriptive passage in a book, there would be the context needed to make the meaning obvious. These kind of sentences very rarely appear completely on their own—either in text or dialogue.

Comment: Thank you as you have answered my question but it is a pity that it was downvoted after you upvoted

Comment: I think there's another meaning for 3. *The girls are enjoyable to be around* [B2 funny and enjoyable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entertaining)

Comment: @Smock You're right! I don't know how I missed that one, but I've added it.

Comment: @JasonBassford. i understand the first sentence in a different way

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao What's your third interpretation of the first sentence?

Comment: @JasonBassford. my interpretation of the first sentence is

Comment: @JasonBassford 1. She loves her dog morethan she loves her husband 2. She loves her dog moretham her husband loves the dog.

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao Neither one of those can be correct, since the syntax of the original sentence has *her dog* as the final item, after the comparative *more than*. In order for the dog to be loved more, it would have to come before *more than*. The thing that is loved (or that loves) less goes after *more than*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97207/discussion-between-jagatha-v-l-narasimharao-and-jason-bassford).

Comment: @JasonBassford.your sentence  is different from mine.please  check what I have written once again

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao Ah! I see my mistake. I don't know how I got the objects of the sentence reversed when I was quoting you. I have corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

A person's first interpretation of such a sentence depends solely upon his or her thought process. "She loves her dog more than her husband" is elliptically ambiguous, wherefore such constructions are uncommon (if not obsolete) in good writing; "They are flying saucers" is ambiguous, for it is confusing whether the pronoun "they" refers to the flying saucers or to the people flying them; and "They are entertaining girls" is ambiguous, for it is confusing whether the pronoun "they" refers to the entertaining girls or to whoever is entertaining them.